History of point-free geometry
I was googling about point-free geometry and saw this passage from the point-free geometry citizendium:

Also, a point-free geometry is considered by J. von Neumann in connection with quantum theory. Indeed, due to Heisenberg’s uncertainty relation, points become meaningless so that one has to replace points by so called “Planck cells”. Von Neumann called the resulting geometry “pointless geometry” which was later on labeled as “noncommutative geometry”.

However, when I read Wikipedia, it seems like point-free geometry is a concept created by a mathematician named Whitehead, and there is no mention of Von Neumann in Wikipedia. I also looked up the book John von Neumann: Selected Letters, which was mentioned in the MathOverFlow answer, but it was difficult to find out clearly.
I'd like to know more about the history of point-free geometry.
Edit:
The book mentioned, Continuous Geometry, seems to be a bit difficult to read, so could you recommend an easier book that focuses on historical content?

In your first link it cites: von Neumann , Continuous geometry, Princeton University Press.

@Mauricio Thanks! I will find it!

As an aside, you might also be interested in learning about point-free topology.

@Alexis: I remember this causing confusion (non-joke taken as a joke) in sci.math at least once. For example, see these 12 March 2009 sci.math posts -- 1 and 2.
